# Facebook Events Manager revoke access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events, facebook-business-manager

I was following Facebook's docs on creating test events and standing up a direct integration for their conversion API server side. Part of the getting started guide had me generate an access token from the Events Manager settings tab. How can I revoke the access token I created? There doesn't seem to be any way from Events Manager.